# Plan capacity for SP 2010 site based on response time

Tags: sharepoint-online

I need to plan capacity for SharePoint 2010 site for a user response time of 2 sec.

Is there a formula or any resources to plan capacity provided by Microsoft?

Comment: A (user) response time? You expect users to respond in 2 seconds or do you want a typical page render time of 2 seconds?

Comment: We want the page to render in max 2 seconds. 
Also, the client wants a page having 2-4 images with some content (from list) to load in 1-2 sec.

Comment: It's a complex subject and you can't realistically guarantee load times from such a system, only best endeavours. Even on the fastest systems, I frequently see 7+ seconds for some pages. There's a lot of dependencies to counteract.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Capacity Planning, baseline is [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff758645%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

Note, that depending on the operations required, only some pages will be capable of rendering in 2 seconds or less. In practice < 2 seconds is difficult to achieve even with serious horsepower in the servers and superb network bandwidth, not to mention the client side software requirements.